# How can i remove number of activity from activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I have four activity (A, B, C, D) and the sequence can be anything like  ( Depends of the requirement on runtime )

Code for Class A is Like This, We get the activity name from the server api response and pass it to the common class to move to another activity -

```
class A extends Activity{

   // Other Code of Activity 

    int backCount = getbackCountFromResponse();  // by calling any service

    String name = getActivityNameFromResponse(); // by calling any service

    Move m  = new Move(this);
    m.go(name);


    onBackPressed(){

        // What will be the code to move back according to number of back count
    }
}
```

Code for Class B is Like This, We get the activity name from the server api response and pass it to the common class to move to another activity -

```
class B extends Activity{

    int backCount = getbackCountFromResponse();  // by calling any service

    String name = getActivityNameFromResponse(); // by calling any service

    Move m  = new Move(this);
    m.go(name);

    onBackPressed(){

    // What will be the code to move back according to number of back count
    }
}
```

Code for Class B is Like This, We get the activity name from the server api response and pass it to the common class to move to another activity -

```
 class C extends Activity{

    // Other Code of Activity 


    int backCount = getbackCountFromResponse();  // by calling any service

    String name = getActivityNameFromResponse(); // by calling any service

    Move m  = new Move(this);
    m.go(name);

    onBackPressed(){

    // What will be the code to move back according to number of back count
    }

}
```

Code for Class B is Like This, We get the activity name from the server api response and pass it to the common class to move to another activity -

```
 class D extends Activity{

   // Other Code of Activity     

    int backCount = getbackCountFromResponse();  // by calling any service

    String name = getActivityNameFromResponse(); // by calling any service

    Move m  = new Move(this);
    m.go(name);

    onBackPressed(){

    // What will be the code to move back according to number of back count
    }

}
```

Code for Common method "go" for move to any of the activity -

```
 class Move {

     Context con;
     public Move(Context con){
           this.con = con;
      }


     public void go(String activityname)
     {

         Intent i = new Intent(con, activityname.class)
         this.con.startActivity(i);   

     }
}
```

I want to remove the number of activity that count comes from the service from current position how can i remove.

Comment: Confusing equation, not able to understand!

Comment: I have update the question please check again if it is understandable

Comment: @SamosysTechnologies look at my answer below, Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the previous task from the stack of the activities and want to make your another activity at the top of the stack then you should try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you do not want to clear your previous task and just want to bring your previous Activity to front then add these two flags like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it will help you.